# New Git branch without changes from a previous commit

Tags: git, repository, branch, git-revert

My current branches look like:

```
     D  
    /
H--A--B--C
```

I was trying to work out how to produce a new git branch which would make the new git repo to looks something like:

```
     D  
    /
H--A--B--C  
    \
     C
```

Is this possible to do? I thought about using reset but that would mean changes from C would also be lost, so looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK so found a way to do this.

I created a new branch with A in it:

```
git branch new-branch <A sha1>
```

Then I used cherry pick to merge C with A in the new-branch:

```
git checkout new-branch
git cherry-pick <C sha1>
```

And that made the repo with the branches I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    C                     A--D  
   /                     /
  A*--D                 H--A--B--C  
 /                       \
H--A--B--C                A--C
    (1)                     (2)
```

Because `(1)` is an equivalent if `(2)` you can just `git checkout <commit sha1 of A*> -b your-new-branch`

Comment: That didn't work it just made a new branch with commits in A included in it i.e. the same as doing git branch <branchname> <branch A* hash>

Comment: thanks for the response though, I'm currently looking at cherry pick sounds like it might work